# How to access CUPS web page config from another device in the network?

Tags: server, printing

I've wanted to config CUPS for my printer, but because I'm running a command-only version of Raspbian, I don't have access to the browser on this device.

I've followed the CUPS installation and config from this [site](https://samhobbs.co.uk/2014/07/raspberry-pi-print-scanner-server).

So I've looked up my IP address, I pinged it from my other device - it worked. I've opened the browser, put the IP along with 631 port but there's an error: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Can I somehow change the config in `cupsd.conf` file to make it work?

Comment: It should be possible to remote into the Pi using SSH, then use a series of Linux commands to find and edit the file as you need.

Comment: Well... I can connect to Pi directly and run `nano cupsd.conf` but that's not the point. I'd like to see CUPS website on another device - PC

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a rather old post, but I had the same issue.  From what I can tell you need to "restart" cups after the changes, not just "reload"

sudo service cups restart

My guess is at some point you rebooted the pi which restarted the service and made it start working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is awkward.

After few hours I just connected the printer via USB and tried the webpage. I haven't changed the configuration and I don't believe that connecting the driver somehow matters but it works now:

[image: cups webpage]

EDIT:

I've just reminded myself that I followed the steps from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/samba-printserver.html) to install samba. Maybe it did the job.